# ATI GPU for mining with display attached to integrated graphics?

Tags: miner-configuration, ubuntu, linux, gpu-mining, mining-setup

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 and I'd like to attach my monitor to the onboard Intel graphic and have my GPU (ATI 67xx) for mining solely.

So far I'm struggling with setting up the ATI GPU. Do I need to run 2 XServers? Or 2 displays with one XServer?

Did anyone get a setup like this to work?